# I can't repeat a rows by javascript .. details here

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table and I want from user add rows which who want. I was looking in google about this way , And I found cods but It dosen't work.

This is my code

Plz help me where is the problem in It.

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
                function addRow(r){
                    var root = r.parentNode;//the root
                    var allRows = root.getElementsByTagName('tr');//the rows' collection
                    var cRow = allRows[0].cloneNode(true)//the clone of the 1st row
                    var cInp = cRow.getElementsByTagName('table');//the inputs' collection of the 1st row
                    for(var i=0;i<cInp.length;i++){//changes the inputs' names (indexes the names)
                cInp[i].setAttribute('name', cInp[1].getAttribute('name') + '_' + (allRows.length + 1));
                }
                var cSel = cRow.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
                    cSel.setAttribute('name',cSel.getAttribute('name')+'_'+(allRows.length+1));//change the selecet's name
                    root.appendChild(cRow);//appends the cloned row as a new row
                }


                function deleteRow(r){
                var i=r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;

                document.getElementById('table2000').deleteRow(1);
                }
                </script>
                </head>
                <body>
<table style="width:950px">
<tr>
                <th align="center" rowspan="2">Program</th>
                <th align="center" colspan="2">Time</th>
                <th align="center" rowspan="2">Pm/Am</th>
                <th align="center" rowspan="2">Price</th>
                <th align="center" rowspan="2">Note</th>
                <th align="center" rowspan="2">Ration</th>
                <th align="center"rowspan="2" >Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>to</th>

            </tr>



<tr>
<td>
<select name="program[]" width="200%;">

                               <OPTION >Option 1</OPTION>
                                <OPTION >Option 2</OPTION>
                                <OPTION >Option 3</OPTION>
                                <OPTION >Option 4</OPTION>
                         </select>
</td>
<td>
                    <select name="from[]" width="70"  >
                        <option>1 </option>
                        <option>2 </option>
                        <option>3 </option>
                        <option>4 </option>
                        <option>5 </option>
                        <option>6 </option>
                        <option>7 </option>
                        <option>8</option>
                        <option>9</option>
                        <option>10</option>
                        <option>11</option>
                        <option>12</option>
                    </select>

</td>
<td>
                    <select name="to[]">
                        <option>1 </option>
                        <option>2 </option>
                        <option>3 </option>
                        <option>4 </option>
                        <option>5 </option>
                        <option>6 </option>
                        <option>7 </option>
                        <option>8</option>
                        <option>9</option>
                        <option>10</option>
                        <option>11</option>
                        <option>12</option>
                    </select>

</td>
<td>
    <select name="time[]">
        <option value="ص">am</option>
        <option value="م">pm</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" value="" name="massat[]">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" value=""  name="note[]">
</td>
<td>                    
    <input type="text" value="" name="rating[]">
</td>
<td>
 <img class="add" src="http://almedinah.net/wp-content/themes/blogitty/images/add-button.png" style=":hover{background:#000;}"onclick="addRow(this.parentNode.parentNode)">
 <img class="add" src="http://almedinah.net/wp-content/themes/blogitty/images/remove-button.png" style=":hover{background:#000;}"onclick="deleteRow(this)">

 </td>

</tr>
</table>
                </body></html>
```

Comment: Please don't urge for answers. "Does not work" is an extremely poor description.

Comment: can you test it plz. in your computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to fix it as below; please note that if you use php, the input name with subscript [] will be automatically assigned an index (hence no need to calculate an index in your javascript and I commented those lines out ).

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">

                function addRow(r){
                    var root = r.parentNode;//the root
                    var allRows = root.getElementsByTagName('tr');//the rows' collection
                    //var cRow = allRows[0].cloneNode(true)//the clone of the 1st row
                    var cRow = allRows[2].cloneNode(true)//the clone of the 1st row
                    //var cInp = cRow.getElementsByTagName('table');//the inputs' collection of the 1st row
                    /*
                    var cInp = cRow.getElementsByTagName('input');//the inputs' collection of the 1st row
                    for(var i=0;i<cInp.length;i++){//changes the inputs' names (indexes the names)
                        //cInp[i].setAttribute('name', cInp[1].getAttribute('name') + '_' + (allRows.length + 1));
                        cInp[i].setAttribute('name', cInp[i].getAttribute('name') );
                    }
                //var cSel = cRow.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
                var cSel = cRow.getElementsByTagName('select');
                for(var i=0;i<cSel.length;i++){
                    //cSel.setAttribute('name',cSel.getAttribute('name')+'_'+(allRows.length+1));//change the selecet's name
                    cSel[i].setAttribute('name',cSel[i].getAttribute('name'));//change the selecet's name
                    }
                    */
                    root.appendChild(cRow);//appends the cloned row as a new row
                }


                function deleteRow(r){
                var i=r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
                    if (i != 2)
                    document.getElementById('table2000').deleteRow(i);
                }
                </script>
                </head>
                <body>
<table style="width:950px" border="2" id="table2000">
<tr>
                <th align="center" rowspan="2">Program</th>
                <th align="center" colspan="2">Time</th>
                <th align="center" rowspan="2">Pm/Am</th>
                <th align="center" rowspan="2">Price</th>
                <th align="center" rowspan="2">Note</th>
                <th align="center" rowspan="2">Ration</th>
                <th align="center"rowspan="2" >Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>to</th>

            </tr>



<tr>
<td>
<select name="program[]" width="200%;">

                               <OPTION >Option 1</OPTION>
                                <OPTION >Option 2</OPTION>
                                <OPTION >Option 3</OPTION>
                                <OPTION >Option 4</OPTION>
                         </select>
</td>
<td>
                    <select name="from[]" width="70"  >
                        <option>1 </option>
                        <option>2 </option>
                        <option>3 </option>
                        <option>4 </option>
                        <option>5 </option>
                        <option>6 </option>
                        <option>7 </option>
                        <option>8</option>
                        <option>9</option>
                        <option>10</option>
                        <option>11</option>
                        <option>12</option>
                    </select>

</td>
<td>
                    <select name="to[]">
                        <option>1 </option>
                        <option>2 </option>
                        <option>3 </option>
                        <option>4 </option>
                        <option>5 </option>
                        <option>6 </option>
                        <option>7 </option>
                        <option>8</option>
                        <option>9</option>
                        <option>10</option>
                        <option>11</option>
                        <option>12</option>
                    </select>

</td>
<td>
    <select name="time[]">
        <option value="?">am</option>
        <option value="?">pm</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" value="" name="massat[]">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" value=""  name="note[]">
</td>
<td>                    
    <input type="text" value="" name="rating[]">
</td>
<td>
 <img class="add" src="http://almedinah.net/wp-content/themes/blogitty/images/add-button.png" style=":hover{background:#000;}"onclick="addRow(this.parentNode.parentNode)">
 <img class="add" src="http://almedinah.net/wp-content/themes/blogitty/images/remove-button.png" style=":hover{background:#000;}"onclick="deleteRow(this)">

 </td>

</tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Comment: But i think there is some problem.suppose if  user clicked on 4th row but new row will be get cloned from always first row.

Comment: well... I don't know the specific requirements. You can change the script to fit your need . For example, one can modify the code to get the rowIndex (just like the deleteRow example ), and then use the rowIndex to calculate which row to clone .

Answer (score 1):

On line 13, you're attempting to get a `select` element in cRow, but cRow doesn't contain a select element; it only contains table headers. It looks like you're after table row 3 (aka `allRows[2]`). There's no select element in that either, but it contains table columns that have the input fields.

You may want to consider starting from scratch, markup-wise. I wasn't able to save this code in the HTML markup's current state.